# How to add numbers in array via a loop in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var arr: Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I can add these numbers to an array separately like this but how do I add 1 to 50 at once instead of typing it all the way through?

```
for (var i:Number=1; i<=50;i++){
var arr:Array(i) = [i];
}

function randomize(a: * , b: * ): int {
    return (Math.random() > .5) ? 1 : -1;
}

trace(arr.sort(randomize));
```

I am trying to implement something like this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple. You can address the **Array**'s elements via square bracket notation. Works both ways:

```
// Assign 1 to 10-th element of Array A.
A[10] = 1;

// Output the 10-th element of A.
trace(A[10]);
```

Furthermore, you don't even need to allocate elements in advance, **Flash Player** will automatically adjust the length of the **Array**:

```
// Declare the Array variable.
var A:Array;

// Initialize the Array. You cannot work with Array before you initialize it.
A = new Array;

// Assign some random elements.
A[0] = 1;
A[3] = 2;

// This will create the following A = [1, null, null, 2]
```

So, your script is about right:

```
// Initialize the Array.
var arr:Array = new Array;

// Iterate from 1 to 50.
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 50; i++)
{
    // Assign i as a value to the i-th element.
    arr[i] = i;
}
```

Just keep in mind that **Array**s are 0-based, so if you forget about index 0 it will remain unset (it will be **null**).

Comment: It would be better to change "arr[i] = i" to "arr.push(i)", otherwise you have a dangling null value in the first position of the array (arr[0] will be null if you do arr[i] = i), AND your length property of the array will be 51 instead of 50.

Also, the correct syntax for a definition is "var arr:Array = new Array();" or "var arr:Array = [];"

Comment: @Joseph 1. At the end of my answer I put a note about **null** at zero index. As you can see, I am fully aware. But OP for some reason leaves it intact so did I. 2. The **var arr:Array = new Array;** line is also a correct way to initialize an **Array**. In AS3 you can omit the constructor brackets with the **new** operator if there are no mandatory arguments.

Comment: certainly, I'm not dismissing your answer. My answer is to help tune thinking around the effect of what he's doing and the styles which are standard. Regards.